# Android - Bundle.putString("anything") fails to add string

Tags: java, android, bundle

i am working on Android project in Android Studio 1.1.0 and i can't pass the message to the handler with Bundle class.

Well, this is my code

```
...
Bundle mUIMessageBundle = new Bundle(newUser.getName());
mUIMessageBundle.putInt("Name", newUser.getName());
mUIMessageBundle.putString("Tag", null);
handler.sendMessage(new android.os.Message());
...
```

The `newUser` is well defined but i have a problem on putInt and putString methods. Those methods execute well, but when i read the message in handler getInt and getString return null. So i debugged a bit and the attached pic will show you the problem. Value-key pairs are added, but on their value places are exceptions like this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Object" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mile.voicenc-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mile.voicenc-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have researched a lot, but i cannot find the solution...

All suggestions will be great, thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Finally i tried to open whole new blank project and i added two lines for intent init:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent("make.your.own.intent");
    intent.putExtra("Name", "asd");
}
...
```

And this code in blank project returned exactly the same exception. It makes me go insane...

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try to clean and build the project.

Comment: Tried, not working. Thank you @balachandarkm

Comment: Try using `Intent` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually attaching the bundle to the message before sending it. Also, call `Handler.obtainMessage()` to get a message, don't create it with `new`:

```
Bundle mUIMessageBundle = new Bundle(newUser.getName());
mUIMessageBundle.putInt("Name", newUser.getName());
mUIMessageBundle.putString("Tag", null);
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(); // get a message
// msg.what = 1; // set type of message
msg.setData(mUIMessageBundle); // attach bundle
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: in the meantime, i found on Android doc that .obtainMessage is better... Thanks

Comment: Nope, i can't call setData() on Bundle object.

Comment: You call it on the Message object, not the Bundle object

Comment: WTF, restarted my PC and everything works. Thank you guys very much

Comment: Just a begginer here... Sorry